# Visual Studio Code doesn´t move to next line usign asyncio and pyppeteer

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

My goal is to open an browser using pyppeteer and creating a new tab. But Visual Studio stops executing the code after the `browser = await launch(headless=False)` line.
But executing the same code in for Example Thonny does work.

Any Help?

Here is the code (its just an example form the internet):

````
import asyncio

from pyppeteer import launch
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/")
    doc = pq(await page.content())
    print("Quotes:", doc(".quote").length)
    await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result your code run in my project, which opened a blank browser window:

[image]

Open Command Palette and choose `Python: Clear Internal Extension Cache`.

If not help, open a new project, create a new virtual environment and select it as interpreter. See [create a virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment).